# inner select statement not registering as a single-group function... "not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to put everything in one sql statement for a report because of the reporting software I'm using.  However, Oracle SQL doesn't seem to be letting me create an inner select with a single-group result even though it has only 1 result in the end product.  (All the other results are single-group functions).
Here's my SQL:

```
select   
COUNT(*) as TOTAL_RXS, 
SUM(rx_tx.brand_acquisition_cost) as TOTAL_COST,
SUM(case rx_tx.drug_dispensed 
    when 'B' then (rx_tx.brand_price - rx_tx.brand_discount)
when 'G' then (rx_tx.generic_price - rx_tx.generic_discount)
end) 
    as TOTAL_PRICE,
 SUM(case rx_tx.drug_dispensed
    when 'B' then (rx_tx.brand_price - rx_tx.brand_discount - rx_tx.brand_acquisition_cost)
when 'G' then (rx_tx.generic_price - rx_tx.generic_discount - rx_tx.brand_acquisition_cost)
end)
as TOTAL_PROFIT

    , (select 
   SUM(tx_tp.balance_due_from_tp)
       from eps2.tx_tp 
   join eps2.rx_tx on rx_tx.id = tx_tp.rx_tx_id
       where 1=1
-- This results in CLAIM STATUS being 'F'
    AND rx_tx.fill_date is not NULL 
    AND rx_tx.returned_date is not NULL 
    AND rx_tx.reportable_sales_date is NULL
    AND (tx_tp.paid_status like '%PAID%' 
    OR tx_tp.paid_status like '%PART%') ) as TOTAL_RECEIVABLES

from eps2.vw_rx_summary join eps2.rx_tx
     on vw_rx_summary.last_filled_rx_tx_id = rx_tx.id
-- where TRUNC(rx_tx.fill_date,'DD') = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 1,'DD')
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your query is missing a `from` statement for the outer query.  If this isn't the complete query, then please show the complete query.

Comment: Sorry... I was adding simplicity and protecting company sql code assets by not including some parts of the query.  But here's the full query.  Thanks.

Comment: This "masking" or type conversion as I'd like to call it doesn't seem to work for me.  It's saying "Exception:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00936: missing expression"

Answer (score 1):

```
select   COUNT(*) as TOTAL_RXS, 
     SUM(rx_tx.brand_acquisition_cost) as TOTAL_COST,
     MAX(select 
        SUM(tx_tp.balance_due_from_tp) as total_receivables
      from eps2.tx_tp 
        join eps2.rx_tx on rx_tx.id = tx_tp.rx_tx_id
      where 1=1
      AND (tx_tp.paid_status like '%PAID%' 
      OR tx_tp.paid_status like '%PART%') ) as total_receivables
```

Adding a `MAX()` for `total_receivables` to mask it as a *aggregate* function!